# Expected expression before equation in C

Tags: c, math, expression, lvalue

I'm making a little C program that works out the area and circumference of circles, and I want this equation to be worked out, but each time it says "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" for the top line, and "expected expression before "=" token" for the second line I've tried everything i can think of, but nothing seems to be working. I've read other articles on things like this, but I couldn't work it out.

```
(float)circ_area = (CircleRadi * CircleRadi) * 3.1415926538;
(float)circ_circum; = (CircleRadi * 2 )* 3.1415926538;
```

This is just during the middle of the code, not within any loops or anything. I can post the whole code if you want.

Comment: As AntohH suggested in his answer, just make sure that **earlier** in your code you have both `float circ_area = 0.0;` and `float circ_circum = 0.0;` so that the variables are declared to be `type float`, and in good practice initialized (in this case to 0.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your 2 lines with:

```
circ_area = (CircleRadi * CircleRadi) * 3.1415926538;
circ_circum = (CircleRadi * 2 )* 3.1415926538;
```

I'm supposing that `circ_area` and `circ_circum` are both `floats` and have been declared previously.